# Compute (set) difference between arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I going to implement ACL (Access control list) in my php website.

In my system user have sum a of roles and permission.

Main algorithm is as follows:

```
permissions = (permissions_by_role + permission_for_user) - user_banned_permission
```

so I have three arrays and get those values from database.

For the first part I use this

```
 $permissions = array_unique(array_merge($permission_by_role, $permission_by_user));
```

How can I remove my banned permission from permission array?
Now I have these two arrays:

```
$permissions and $permission_banned_for_user[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a perfect use-case for [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$permissions = array_diff($permissions, $permission_banned_for_user);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) - Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference.

```
$allowed    = array('view', 'create', 'edit', 'delete', 'add');
$banned     = array('add', 'delete');
$result = array_diff($allowed, $banned);
print_r($result); //Array ( [0] => view [1] => create [2] => edit )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the situation correctly you can do this easily by using the array_diff() function. Have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

This will take 2 arrays and return all elements that are in array 1 and not in array 2.