# Making array from two arrays arrays by comparing values in php

Tags: php

I want to create an array which would contain difference of two arrays and the difference is value not key.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Creator
    [1] => HOD
)
Array
(
    [0] => Manager
    [1] => Creator
    [2] => HOD
)
```

I want manager as an output. The sequence of arrays should not matter.

Comment: Use `array_diff`. This function will be the first when you search `array difference`.

Comment: Please read about all functions related about php array you will seed [`array_diff`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_diff)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute (set) difference between arrays in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510005/compute-set-difference-between-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

In example :

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array("creator", "hod");
$arr2 = array("manager", "creator", "hod");

$result = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
//                       ^------^------ notice the order

var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'manager' (length=7)
```

This will result the elements of the **first** parameter that are not in the second.

---

If you are doing :

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array("creator", "hod");
$arr2 = array("manager", "creator", "hod");

$result = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
//                       ^------^------ notice the order
var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Output is empty because there is no element in the first array that aren't in the second one.

---

If you want to get both differences (the elements that are in first array and not in second **and** the elements that are in the second array and not in the first one), you can combine twice `array_diff()` and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

In example :

```
$arr1 = array("creator", "hod", "developper");
$arr2 = array("manager", "creator", "hod");

$result1 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$result2 = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);

$result = array_merge($result1, $result2);

var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'developper' (length=10)
  1 => string 'manager' (length=7
```

Comment: keys are diffrent

Comment: If it doesn't work as you expect, then your question is badly written. *"the difference is value not key"*